# How to build my MySQL script and table in my container with an attached terminal and a dockerfile

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, containers

Here's a sample for Mysql and I create a dockerfile as my photo here

My database needs:
Tech MySQL
Database table: user
Database fields:user_name|password|Type

However, I don't why it doesn't appear.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgwCk.jpg)

```
from mysql:latest
copy script.mysql
cmd  bash script_mysql
```

I build it but get "failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: dockerfile parse error line 2: COPY requires at least two arguments, but only one was provided. Destination could not be determined."

Answer (score 1):

actualy you have got a syntax error in your docker file, for the COPY commands in docker build you need to specify the  destination directory, where you want to copy the script.mysql file in container:

```
COPY script.mysql <destination_directory_in_container>
```

Add to that there are missing configurations in your Dockerfile check the [mysql_images_docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) form more infos.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm trying!

Comment: You are welcome, I'll be thankfull if you accept the answer while it is helpful

Comment: I'll accept it after I finish building my database script and table in my container with an attached terminal and a dockerfile. ;-)

Comment: It's so difficult for a newbie like me. I'm doing my best to achieve it so I can verify your answer to accept your answer. (lol)